# Protocol defining singleton with properties

Tags: swift, singleton, protocols

I have the following protocol that defines a singleton with property:

```
protocol SingletonProtocol {
    static var shared: SingletonProtocol { get }
    var variable : Int { get set }
}
```

And the following class that implements this protocol:

```
class Singleton : SingletonProtocol{
    static let shared : SingletonProtocol = Singleton()
    var variable = 4
}
```

If I call:

```
Singleton.shared.variable = 5
```

I get the following error:

```
 change 'let' to 'var' to make it mutable
```

If I implement this class without the protocol I don't get the error and the variable can be changed. I can solve this by adding `setVariable:` method but I want to access and modify the variable directly.

How can I write a protocol that defines a singleton with variables that can be modified?

Comment: You can't really ensure that a conforming type only has a singleton instance, since for that you'd need to declare a private initializer in your class, which you can do, but you can't declare it in `SingletonProtocol`, so a class can conform to your protocol without having only a singleton instance. With your current implementation, it is possible to instantiate any number of `Singleton` instances.

Comment: Thank you @DávidPásztor for this comment, is there a way for a protocol to "enforce" private init in its comforting protocols.

Comment: Sadly no, you can't mark protocol methods as private.

Comment: You can set it like `var shared = Singleton.shared
 shared.variable = 5`

Comment: I'm curious, why do you need a protocol here? What other types would conform to `SingletonProtocol`?

Comment: I want to unitest a singleton class using dependency injection and for that I need a variable in the protocol with the type of an other protocol to set as a mock in the testing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the protocol available only for classes (struct won't be able to conform to this protocol):

```
protocol SingletonProtocol: AnyObject {
    static var shared: SingletonProtocol { get }
    var variable: Int { get set }
}
```

Now you can set the `shared` property as a let

```
class Singleton: SingletonProtocol {
    static let shared: SingletonProtocol = Singleton()
    var variable: Int = 0
}
```

Comment: In your class, don't forget to make your init private

Comment: 1) with private set I get the error "cannot assign to property: 'shared' setter is inaccessible"


2) how does making it only for classes help me?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake; that problem is about struct, which are value-types; I changed answer. If a protocol is only for classes, it means that only reference-types can conform to it; a reference type can be immutable even if its members aren't. So now you can use let instead of var

Comment: If I do, the class will not be a singleton anymore, shared must be immutable.

Comment: If you do this, in the class you can declare shared as let, so it’s immutable

Comment: And back to the original problem, if I try to do Singleton.shared.variable = 2 I get the error '"change 'let' to 'var' to make it mutable"

Comment: I'm testing in Playground and it works good for me, swift 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
static let shared : SingletonProtocol = Singleton()
```

to

```
static var shared : SingletonProtocol = Singleton()
private init() {}
```

Comment: If I do, the class will not be a singleton anymore, shared must be immutable.

Comment: If you add `private init() {}` there shouldn’t be much potential left for more than a single instance.

Comment: How can a var remains immutable?

Comment: Good point. However, how would you change it in the case above once it has been initially set?

Answer (score -2):

In your singleton class change the variable declaration from let to var. so that will be same as in protocol's declaration.

```
class Singleton : SingletonProtocol{
    static var shared : SingletonProtocol = Singleton()
    var variable = 4
}
```

EDIT:

also add only getter for sharedInstance in protocol declaration to serve purpose of singleton class as:

```
protocol SingletonProtocol: AnyObject {
    static var shared: SingletonProtocol { get }
    var variable: Int { get set }
}
```

Comment: If I do, the class will not be a singleton anymore, shared must be immutable.

Comment: @amir check the tom's comment above, same can be applicable here.

Comment: yes but I still want shared to be let because it is the correct way of writing singleton, so the correct solution is Rico Crescenzio's